# Is group homomorphism $F: SO(3) \to \mathbb R-\{0\}$ unique?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, axiom-of-choice

If we assume that $F$ is smooth, then such $F$ is unique. Under this assumption, the question is equivalent to find all 1-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$, and by considering Lie algebra there is only the trivial one.

But what if we remove the smoothness assumption? I think this question may be related to the fact that there are "nontrivial" $\mathbb Q$-linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, which can be constructed by using the axiom of choice.

Comment: As I answered a few times before, under certain conditions (without choice, that is) such as all sets are Lebesgue measurable, any group homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous.

Comment: As regards smooth vs continuous, it is true (and in most Lie groups textbooks) that any continuous homomorphism between Lie groups is smooth (and even $\mathbf{R}$-analytic if the Lie groups are assumed so). However in ZFC continuity fails, typically between abelian groups, or also inside complex simple Lie groups using non-continuous field automorphisms of $\mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's unique: indeed, the group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is perfect: actually every element is a commutator.

Indeed, consider any element $q$: this is a rotation; hence square of another rotation (with same axis) $r$, namely $q=r^2$. Then $r$ and $r^{-1}$ being rotations of the same angle, are conjugate (by any element reversing the axis of $r$): $r^{-1}=srs^{-1}$. So $q=r^2=r(r^{-1})^{-1}=rsr^{-1}s^{-1}$.